# Defining pretty urls for Rails 4 and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate for my home page of the application which is the home action of the static_pages controller.

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

The will_paginate URLs are as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home?page=3
```

I would prefer to take out the controller name in there and have it look like

```
http://localhost:3000/home?page=3
```

Or even something prettier like

```
http://localhost:3000/home/3
```

My pagination looks like this

```
will_paginate @product_feed_items, :page_links => false, :previous_label => "Newer", :next_label => "Older"
```

and I have tried a couple things like this with no luck

```
will_paginate(@product_feed_items, :params => { :controller => "static_pages", :action => "home" }, :page_links => false, :previous_label => "Newer", :next_label => "Older")
```

Does anything have a good solution for this??

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to do this only for few actions try this:

```
get "home(/:page)" => "static_pages#home"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this via the routes.rb file. Have a look at the routing guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Specifically section 3 on non-resourceful routes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that resource. I will definitely look into it